# How do you pass an Objective-C NSError pointer into a Swift function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pointers, nserror

I'm implementing Swift data structures into Objective-C and I'm having trouble 'returning' 2 values.

My swift implementation originally used a tuple to return resultData AND an error:

```
func getData(email: String) -> (SomeResultdata?, NSError?)
```

but this function isn't exposed to Objective-C due to tuples not being a feature in Objective-C.
I've now implemented a method dedicated to returning SomeResultData exclusively, but also assigning an NSError to the passed pointer reference.
See below:

```
@objc func getData(email: String, var withError err: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>) -> SomeResultdata? {
  let (credentials, error) = self.getData(email)
  // This self.getData(email) is the Swift implementation (returns tuple)
  err = &error
  return credentials
}
```

The two errors I'm getting are

**Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C**

and

**Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'inout $T2'**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject()` has similar pattern:

```
class func dataWithJSONObject(obj: AnyObject, options opt: NSJSONWritingOptions, error: NSErrorPointer) -> NSData?
```

It's `NSErrorPointer`.

```
typealias NSErrorPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>
```

So you can:

```
@objc func getData(email: String, withError err: NSErrorPointer) -> SomeResultdata? {
    let (credentials, error) = self.getData(email)
    // This self.getData(email) is the Swift implementation (returns tuple)
    err.memory = error
    return credentials
}
```

As for `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/autoreleasingunsafemutablepointer).

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the .memory property. Was exactly what I needed to get things working!